# Visual Studio 2010 crashing 10-20 times a day

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ultimately, this may have now been resolved after completely removing and re-installing the .NET framework and Visual Studio 2010, and then running CCleaner on my registry.  Not seen the error for a few days now so I'm hoping it has gone away for good.  Thanks all for suggestions.

In summary, I have VS2010 professional (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) and using it for VB.NET development at the moment with AnkhSVN and Tortoise latest versions.  It crashes with no detail other than:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77d415de in devenv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: VBRuntimeException at memory location 0x08e0f594..
```

And it happens 10-20 times a day and is becoming a nightmare.  I have re-installed the whole thing (not just repaired).  I have deleted all temp files, .suo , .user etc and switched off hardware acceleration.  None of this has helped.  If I debug the crash, I get the following stack:

> ```
>   ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
>   ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
>   KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()  + 0x58 bytes   
>   msvcr100.dll!__CxxThrowException@8()  + 0x45 bytes  
> > msvbide.dll!PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes()  + 0xb5422 bytes    
>   msvbide.dll!PEBuilder::Compile()  + 0x14b591 bytes  
>   msvbide.dll!CompilerProject::_PromoteToCompiled()  + 0xa9 bytes 
>   msvbide.dll!CompilerProject::CompileFromBoundToCompiled()  + 0x32b38 bytes  
>   msvbide.dll!CompilerPackage::CompileFromBoundToCompiled()  + 0x1f bytes 
>   msvbide.dll!CompilerPackage::CompileAllProjects()  - 0x419 bytes    
>   msvbide.dll!CompilerPackage::BackgroundTask()  + 0x68 bytes 
>   msvbide.dll!ThreadSyncManager::ThreadProc()  + 0xd2 bytes   
>   kernel32.dll!769233aa()     
>   [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]  
>   ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
>   ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
> ```

In Define PIATypes I can see the following with references to vftable and conditions not being met but can't see what exactly is causing the crash.  If anyone can make sense of it, it would be hugely appreciated as I've spent hours trying to work it out.

The finger of suspicion points to either AnkhSVN, TortoiseSVN or a (now uninstalled) Resharper trial.  Particularly the latter as it's the only difference to my colleague, who runs the same solution with a similar box, same vs2010 build and has no problems at all

> 5926B73E  mov         ecx,edi   5926B740  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+70h],0   5926B748  call
>   BCSYM_NamedRoot::GetQualifiedNameHelper (59006C83h)   5926B74D  mov
>   esi,dword ptr [esp+40h]   5926B751  mov         edx,dword ptr
>   [esi-0Ch]   5926B754  mov         dword ptr [esp+28h],edx   5926B758 
>   movzx       eax,byte ptr [edi]   5926B75B  test        byte ptr
>   BCSYM::s_rgBilkindInfo (59001BD8h)[eax+eax*2],8   5926B763  je
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+30Eh (5926B7BEh)   5926B765  test
>   byte ptr BCSYM::s_rgBilkindInfo+1 (59001BD9h)[eax+eax*2],bl   5926B76C
>   je          PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+2D4h (5926B784h)   5926B76E  mov
>   ecx,dword ptr [edi+4Ch]   5926B771  call
>   BCSYM::DigThroughNamedType (59002029h)   5926B776  mov         ecx,eax
>   5926B778  call        BCSYM::PNamedRoot (59001F9Ch)   5926B77D  call
>   BCSYM::PContainer (59001C60h)   5926B782  jmp
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+2D6h (5926B786h)   5926B784  mov
>   eax,edi   5926B786  cmp         dword ptr [eax+4Ch],0   5926B78A  je
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+30Eh (5926B7BEh)   5926B78C  movzx
>   eax,byte ptr [edi]   5926B78F  test        byte ptr
>   BCSYM::s_rgBilkindInfo+1 (59001BD9h)[eax+eax*2],bl   5926B796  je
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+304h (5926B7B4h)   5926B798  mov
>   ecx,dword ptr [edi+4Ch]   5926B79B  call
>   BCSYM::DigThroughNamedType (59002029h)   5926B7A0  mov         ecx,eax
>   5926B7A2  call        BCSYM::PNamedRoot (59001F9Ch)   5926B7A7  call
>   BCSYM::PContainer (59001C60h)   5926B7AC  mov         eax,dword ptr
>   [eax+4Ch]   5926B7AF  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+70h]   5926B7B2 
>   jmp         PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+327h (5926B7D7h)   5926B7B4  mov
>   eax,edi   5926B7B6  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+4Ch]   5926B7B9 
>   mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+70h]   5926B7BC  jmp
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+327h (5926B7D7h)   5926B7BE  mov
>   eax,edi   5926B7C0  call        BCSYM_NamedRoot::GetContainer
>   (590021A3h)   5926B7C5  test        eax,eax   5926B7C7  je
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+325h (5926B7D5h)   5926B7C9  mov
>   eax,dword ptr [eax+4Ch]   5926B7CC  test        eax,eax   5926B7CE  je
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+325h (5926B7D5h)   5926B7D0  mov
>   eax,dword ptr [eax+70h]   5926B7D3  jmp
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+327h (5926B7D7h)   5926B7D5  xor
>   eax,eax   5926B7D7  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+60h]   5926B7DA 
>   lea         ecx,[esp+68h]   5926B7DE  push        ecx   5926B7DF  lea 
>   ebx,[esp+2Ch]   5926B7E3  lea         edi,[esp+58h]   5926B7E7  mov
>   dword ptr [esp+20h],eax   5926B7EB  call
>   DynamicHashTable >::GetValueInternal (59024E04h)   5926B7F0  test        al,al   5926B7F2  je          PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+379h (5926B829h)
>   5926B7F4  lea         edx,[esp+20h]   5926B7F8  push        edx
>   5926B7F9  call        DynamicHashTable >::GetValueInternal (59024E04h)   5926B7FE  test        al,al   5926B800  je          5926B93A   5926B806  mov         eax,dword ptr
>   [esp+20h]   5926B80A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+1Ch]   5926B80E 
>   mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+18h]   5926B812  mov         edx,dword
>   ptr [edx+30h]   5926B815  push        eax   5926B816  push        ecx 
>   5926B817  push        esi   5926B818  push        0   5926B81A  mov
>   ecx,7B40h   5926B81F  call        ErrorTable::CreateError (59020900h) 
>   5926B824  add         esp,10h   5926B827  jmp
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+38Ch (5926B83Ch)   5926B829  lea
>   eax,[esp+1Ch]   5926B82D  push        eax   5926B82E  lea
>   ecx,[esp+2Ch]   5926B832  push        ecx   5926B833  lea
>   ecx,[esp+5Ch]   5926B837  call        DynamicHashTable >::SetValue (594172E7h)   5926B83C  mov         edi,dword ptr [esp+18h]   5926B840  lea         edx,[esp+30h]   5926B844  push
>   edx   5926B845  add         edi,448h   5926B84B  lea
>   ebx,[esp+28h]   5926B84F  call        DynamicHashTable >::GetValueInternal (594159BEh)   5926B854  test        al,al   5926B856  je          PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+3CAh (5926B87Ah)
>   5926B858  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+30h]   5926B85C  mov
>   eax,dword ptr [esp+4Ch]   5926B860  cmp         dword ptr
>   [eax+ecx*4],0   5926B864  jne         5926B97F   5926B86A  mov
>   edx,dword ptr [esp+24h]   5926B86E  mov         edi,dword ptr
>   [esp+18h]   5926B872  mov         dword ptr [eax+ecx*4],edx   5926B875
>   jmp         PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+1B6h (591B670Bh)   5926B87A  mov
>   edi,dword ptr [esp+24h]   5926B87E  mov         eax,edi   5926B880 
>   call        BCSYM_NamedRoot::GetContainingClassOrInterface (5905D431h)
>   5926B885  test        eax,eax   5926B887  jne         5926B9C4
>   5926B88D  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+2Ch]   5926B891  mov
>   eax,0FEEFEDh   5926B896  mov         dword ptr [esp+104h],eax
>   5926B89D  mov         dword ptr [esp+100h],eax   5926B8A4  lea
>   eax,[esp+100h]   5926B8AB  push        eax   5926B8AC  push        edi
>   5926B8AD  xor         ebx,ebx   5926B8AF  push        ecx   5926B8B0 
>   mov         dword ptr [esp+118h],ebx   5926B8B7  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+114h],ebx   5926B8BE  call
>   MetaEmit::DefineTypeRefByContainer (590B85F4h)   5926B8C3  and
>   eax,0FF000000h   5926B8C8  cmp         eax,2000000h   5926B8CD  jne
>   5926B9FD   5926B8D3  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+14h]   5926B8D7 
>   mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+4Ch]   5926B8DB  cmp         dword ptr
>   [ecx+eax*4],ebx   5926B8DE  jne         5926BA36   5926B8E4  mov
>   dword ptr [ecx+eax*4],edi   5926B8E7  mov         edi,dword ptr
>   [esp+18h]   5926B8EB  inc         eax   5926B8EC  mov         dword
>   ptr [esp+14h],eax   5926B8F0  jmp
>   PEBuilder::DefinePiaTypes+1B6h (591B670Bh)   5926B8F5  lea
>   ecx,[esp+100h]   5926B8FC  call        dword ptr
>   [__imp_std::exception::exception (590013BCh)]   5926B902  mov
>   byte ptr [esp+120h],5   5926B90A  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+100h],offset Exception::`vftable' (592A2F1Ch)   5926B915  mov
>
>   dword ptr [esp+10Ch],offset string L"The condition should"...
>   (592A2E48h)   5926B920  mov         byte ptr [esp+120h],4   5926B928 
>   push        offset __TI1?AVVBRuntimeException@@ (594C15ECh)   5926B92D
>   lea         edx,[esp+104h]   5926B934  push        edx   5926B935 
>   call        __CxxThrowException@8 (59458905h)   5926B93A  lea
>
>   ecx,[esp+100h]   5926B941  call        dword ptr
>   [__imp_std::exception::exception (590013BCh)]   5926B947  mov
>
>   byte ptr [esp+120h],6   5926B94F  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+100h],offset Exception::`vftable' (592A2F1Ch)   5926B95A  mov
>   dword ptr [esp+10Ch],offset string L"Key not present in t"...
>   (592AEDA0h)   5926B965  mov         byte ptr [esp+120h],4   5926B96D 
>   push        offset __TI1?AVVBRuntimeException@@ (594C15ECh)   5926B972
>   lea         eax,[esp+104h]   5926B979  push        eax   5926B97A 
>   call        _*CxxThrowException@8 (59458905h)   5926B97F  lea
>
>   ecx,[esp+100h]   5926B986  call        dword ptr
>   [*_imp_std::exception::exception (590013BCh)]   5926B98C  mov
>   byte ptr [esp+120h],7   5926B994  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+100h],offset Exception::`vftable' (592A2F1Ch)   5926B99F  mov
>
>   dword ptr [esp+10Ch],offset string L"The condition should"...
>   (592AC5A0h)   5926B9AA  mov         byte ptr [esp+120h],4   5926B9B2 
>   push        offset __TI1?AVVBRuntimeException@@ (594C15ECh)   5926B9B7
>   lea         ecx,[esp+104h]   5926B9BE  push        ecx   5926B9BF 
>   call        __CxxThrowException@8 (59458905h)   5926B9C4  lea
>
>   ecx,[esp+30h]   5926B9C8  call        dword ptr
>   [__imp_std::exception::exception (590013BCh)]   5926B9CE  mov
>
>   byte ptr [esp+120h],8   5926B9D6  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+30h],offset Exception::`vftable' (592A2F1Ch)   5926B9DE  mov
>   dword ptr [esp+3Ch],offset string L"The condition should"...
>   (592AC5A0h)   5926B9E6  mov         byte ptr [esp+120h],4   5926B9EE 
>   push        offset __TI1?AVVBRuntimeException@@ (594C15ECh)   5926B9F3
>   lea         edx,[esp+34h]   5926B9F7  push        edx   5926B9F8  call
>   _*CxxThrowException@8 (59458905h)   5926B9FD  lea         ecx,[esp+30h]   5926BA01  call        dword ptr
>   [*_imp_std::exception::exception (590013BCh)]   5926BA07  mov
>   byte ptr [esp+120h],9   5926BA0F  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+30h],offset Exception::`vftable' (592A2F1Ch)   5926BA17  mov
>
>   dword ptr [esp+3Ch],offset string L"The condition should"...
>   (592AC5A0h)   5926BA1F  mov         byte ptr [esp+120h],4   5926BA27 
>   push        offset __TI1?AVVBRuntimeException@@ (594C15ECh)   5926BA2C
>   lea         eax,[esp+34h]   5926BA30  push        eax   5926BA31  call
>   __CxxThrowException@8 (59458905h)   5926BA36  lea         ecx,[esp+30h]   5926BA3A  call        dword ptr
>   [__imp_std::exception::exception (590013BCh)]   5926BA40  mov
>
>   byte ptr [esp+120h],0Ah   5926BA48  mov         dword ptr
>   [esp+30h],offset Exception::`vftable' (592A2F1Ch)   5926BA50  mov
>   dword ptr [esp+3Ch],offset string L"The condition should"...
>   (592AC5A0h)   5926BA58  mov         byte ptr [esp+120h],4   5926BA60 
>   push        offset __TI1?AVVBRuntimeException@@ (594C15ECh)   5926BA65
>   lea         ecx,[esp+34h]   5926BA69  push        ecx   5926BA6A  call
>   __CxxThrowException@8 (59458905h)   5926BA6F  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+4Ch]   5926BA73  mov         esi,dword ptr [ecx+ebx*4]
>   5926BA76  test        esi,esi   5926BA78  je          5926BA98
>   5926BA7A  push        1   5926BA7C  push        ecx   5926BA7D  push
>   esi   5926BA7E  push        edi   5926BA7F  call
>   Builder::GetTypeDef (590B83C5h)   5926BA84  mov         edx,dword ptr
>   [esp+34h]   5926BA88  add         esp,4   5926BA8B  push        eax
>   5926BA8C  push        edi   5926BA8D  mov         ecx,esi   5926BA8F 
>   call        PEBuilder::EmitAttributesAttachedToSymbol (590B948Ah)
>   5926BA94  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+14h]   5926BA98  inc
>   ebx   5926BA99  cmp         ebx,eax   5926BA9B  jae         591B6774
>   5926BAA1  jmp         5926BA6F   5926BAA3  mov         edx,dword ptr
>   [esp+4Ch]   5926BAA7  mov         ecx,dword ptr [edx+esi*4]   5926BAAA
>   test        ecx,ecx   5926BAAC  je          5926BABC   5926BAAE  mov
>   edx,dword ptr [esp+2Ch]   5926BAB2  push        edi   5926BAB3  call
>   PEBuilder::DefineMembersOfPiaType (59416B76h)   5926BAB8  mov
>   eax,dword ptr [esp+14h]   5926BABC  inc         esi   5926BABD  cmp
>   esi,eax   5926BABF  jae         591B677E   5926BAC5  jmp
>   5926BAA3   5926BAC7  mov         edx,dword ptr [edi+30h]   5926BACA 
>   push        0   5926BACC  mov         ecx,781Bh   5926BAD1  call
>   ErrorTable::CreateError (59020900h)   5926BAD6  add         esp,4
>   5926BAD9  jmp         591B67CF   5926BADE  push        eax   5926BADF 
>   mov         eax,dword ptr [g_vbCommonHeap (594EF058h)]   5926BAE4 
>   push        0   5926BAE6  push        eax   5926BAE7  call
>   dword ptr [_*imp*_HeapFree@12 (590011C4h)]   5926BAED  jmp
>   591B67E3   5926BAF2  mov         ebx,dword ptr [ebx+4Ch]   5926BAF5 
>   jmp         PEBuilder::DefineMemberOfContainer+2Bh (591933E9h)
>   5926BAFA  mov         ecx,ebx   5926BAFC  call
>   BCSYM::DigThroughNamedType (59002029h)

Comment: If you want to eliminate the possibility that it's an extension, try [`/SafeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: How much RAM do you have? ReSharper needs about 6Gb to run stably - basically if you have XP then VS will crash quite a lot if you have R# installed.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure it belongs here? StackOverflow is for programming questions - not IDE troubleshooting

Comment: A crash in a function named DefinePiaTypes() points to a sick registry.

Comment: It seems to be crashing on generating the COM Interop assemblies for a COM/OCX component. Is your VB solution referencing one or more of them?

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses.  I have 8GB RAM, SSD and have uninstalled R# so it's not that.  I think the question does belong here as I spend my whole life programming and use VS2010 as my primary tool.  Sick registry would make sense as even an uninstall of VS2010 has not solved the issue.  Re. COM interop, perhaps but other people have exactly the same solution and same COM references (they are part of the project in SVN) and they don't experience the same issue.  I may remove the COM refs as a test to see if it goes away. Last resort is to re-image my machine as I'm running out of ideas

Comment: And re. /SafeMode, I'm pretty sure that makes no difference as I tried it early on and still got the crashes - will double check though

Comment: Just crashed today whilst running in /SafeMode so not that.  May try installing Office PIAs to see if that cleans up the registry